# What is best practice to load text in an MVC website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Can somebody suggest what is the best practice to load text(which has 2-5 paragraphs) in  razor page, either by getting text load from word document(write a c# class to parse word document and through controller pass the data to view) or directly embedding the text in the Razor page ?

Thanks

Comment: If you need html formatted input, try CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: If the text is not dyanamic...i.e it is static for all users then you can directly embed itt in your view

Comment: Razor is used to insert business logic into html. If all you are doing is displaying text, then simply put the HTML for that text in a view / partial view.

Comment: As mentioned you have many options, such as hardcoding, reading it from a database, reading it from an XML file. However just about the worst possible option I can think of is parsing it from a word document.

Comment: @Fishcake unless thats exactly the purpose, ie word file viewer

Comment: @Mladen yeah OK, if that was EXACTLY the requirements then sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect the text to change then just write it in your Razor view.

If the text might change, and you don't want to re-publish every time, then you can have the controller read it from a file or database and pass it to the Razor view.